# Android :: SMS permissions without Telephony

Tags: android, permissions, sms, telephony

My app has SEND_SMS and RECEIVE_SMS permissions, by publishing it gets android.hardware.telephony requirement. As a result the app isn't visible for Galaxy Tab 10.1 in Market (due to 'telephony').

The question is how to avoid android.hardware.telephony (make my app available for Tab 10.1) and be able to use SMS. 
PS Tab has SMS functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add this in your Android Manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```

Then you have to take care for the case where this feature is unavailable.

Comment: Can you please give an example of 'taking care' ?

Comment: If you are going to send or receive SMSs, you will have to make sure your app won't crash on a non-phone device. For example, if you use bluetooth on a phone which does not support BT, and you try to get ahold on the BluetoothAdapter, you will get a null object - since BT doesn't exist. Check out what happens when you get ahold of the SmsManager on a non phone device.